# 'canLaunch' is deprecated in Flutter

Tags: flutter, url, deprecated, url-launcher

I'v used [url_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher) package.

```
String query = Uri.encodeComponent(Utils.getSelectedStoreAddress());
var appleUrl = 'maps:q=$query';
var googleUrl = 'https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=$query';

_launch(appleUrl);
_launch(googleUrl);

Future<void> _launch(String url) async {
await canLaunch(url)
    ? await launch(url)
    : _showSnackBar('could_not_launch_this_app'.tr());
}
```

Everything were OK until I get this warning:

```
info: 'canLaunch' is deprecated and shouldn't be used. Use canLaunchUrl instead.
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I changed my code as below & everything goes OK:

```
String query = Uri.encodeComponent(Utils.getSelectedStoreAddress());
Uri appleUrl = Uri.parse('maps:q=$query');
Uri googleUrl = Uri.parse('https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=$query');


_launch(appleUrl);
_launch(googleUrl);

 Future<void> _launch(Uri url) async {
   await canLaunchUrl(url)
    ? await launchUrl(url)
    : _showSnackBar('could_not_launch_this_app'.tr());
}
```

Comment: Can also use `launchUrlString(url)` but `launchUrl(...)` is recommended in the docs since in the case of `launchUrl(...)`, the plugin makes an effort to make the URL valid (as explained in the docs).

Comment: What about the forceSafariVC in launchUrl ?

Comment: This code works well.